# PHP loop through mysql results and count

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I hate that I can't figure this out and unfortunately I don't have the time to play around to figure out, so any help is appreciate.

I have a table DATA with fields AREAID and AREANAME. 
I need the code to loop through the results 24 times as that's the # of AREAIDs that are available. In the table though, there may only be 10 entries in there. So, maybe no one put in something for AREAID 1. I would still want it to return AREAID1 and say NOT found. When it loops and finds an AREAID 2, it would show the AREANAME.

Hope that is clear as mud. And again, thanks for the help!!

```
$query="select areaid,arename from data";
    $result = do_query($query);
{    $x=0;
     while($row = do_fetch_result($result)){
$x=$x+1;
$areaid=$row['areaid'];
$areaname=$row['arename'];

if ($areaid==$x) {
echo "AreaID:".$areaid;
 echo "found".$x."<br>";
  }
else {
echo "AreaID:".$areaid;
echo "not found".$x."<br>";
}}
```

Comment: YOu have to post the code you have problems with (See Stackoverflow introduction).

Comment: `while($row=sql_stuff){ if($row['x']== 'XX'){ // do something } else{...} }` bay-sick-ah-lee.

Comment: as per your edit... seems I already wrote that ^ so... what's the issue, no results? errors? checking for them?

Comment: @Fred-ii- because row 1 for example, may be areaid 5, since no one put in areaid 1,2,3 or 4 so they won't match.

Comment: Use fetchAll to receive the list. Instead of a `while` use a classic `for` loop to count up the area codes. Then iterate over the fetched list and output matching $areaids then. (Also please reformat your code. Or describe the goal/algorithm in a list.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `x==1` and `AREAID` 1 is missing, and $row['areaid'] ==2, then you do not find the rest.

You do not find 1, you say that it's missing, you increment `x`, which might now match `$row['areaid']` if it is 2, but you also get a new row, losing a possible `AREAID 2` etc.

How about

```
$x=0;
while($row = do_fetch_result($result)){
    $areaid=$row['areaid'];
    $areaname=$row['areaname'];
    while($x < $areaid) {
        echo "AreaID:".$areaid;
        echo "not found".$x."<br>";
        $x=$x+1;
    }
    echo "AreaID:".$areaid;
    echo "found".$x."<br>";
    $x=$x+1;
}
while($x <= 24) {
    echo "AreaID:".$areaid;
    echo "not found".$x."<br>";
    $x=$x+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can`t you just foreach throught all the result ?? And where you have only ID and no value do some if, like below?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="select areaid,arename from data";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// Fetch all
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach($result as $array){
echo $array[areaId] . '=>';
if(!empty($array[areaName])){
   echo $array[areaName] . '<br />';
} else {
    echo 'Not Found<br />';
}
```

Comment: This only shows the ones in the database, not the others I need to show.

Comment: can`t you just add the empty ones to db with a loop, and keep them together ?